# Android gridview don't show data from customview

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout

I develop lockscreen app for android. I must custom view to show it at lockscreen. If i use activity, gridview shows data normal, but when i use it at custom view, it show page empty. Customview is called from Service, not activity.

My code

Customview

```
public class PhotoView extends LinearLayout {

private PhotoView.OnPhotoListener mOnPhotoListener;
private Context mContext;
private View mPhotoView;
private boolean isAttached = false;
private static final String TAG = "PhotoView";
private GridView gridGallery;
private Handler handler;
private PhotoAdapter adapter;

public interface OnPhotoListener {
    void onClose();
}

public void setOnPhotoListener(OnPhotoListener mOnPhotoListener) {
    this.mOnPhotoListener = mOnPhotoListener;
}

public PhotoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mPhotoView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, this, true);
    initView();
}

public PhotoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public PhotoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

private void initView() {
    findViewById(R.id.imgBackPhoto).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    handler = new Handler();
    gridGallery = (GridView) mPhotoView.findViewById(R.id.gridGallery);
    gridGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    adapter = new PhotoAdapter(mContext);
    PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(ImageLoader.getInstance(),
            true, true);
    gridGallery.setOnScrollListener(listener);

    gridGallery.setOnItemClickListener(mItemSingleClickListener);

    gridGallery.setAdapter(adapter);

    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.addAll(getRealPathList());
                    //checkImageStatus();
                }
            });
            Looper.loop();
        };

    }.start();
}

AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemSingleClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        PhotoItemData item = adapter.getItem(position);
        Intent data = new Intent().putExtra("single_path", item.getSdcardPath());
    }
};

public ArrayList<PhotoItemData> getRealPathList() {
    Uri contentUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ArrayList<PhotoItemData> galleryList = new ArrayList<PhotoItemData>();
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            PhotoItemData item = new PhotoItemData();
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            String res = cursor.getString(column_index);
            item.setSdcardPath(res);
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // show newest photo at beginning of the list
    Collections.reverse(galleryList);
    return galleryList;
}

public boolean isAttached() {
    return isAttached;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    isAttached = true;
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    isAttached = false;
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgBackPhoto:
                L.d(TAG, "close");
                mOnPhotoListener.onClose();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
}
```

Adapter

```
public class PhotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater infalter;
private ArrayList<PhotoItemData> data = new ArrayList<>();

public PhotoAdapter(Context context) {
    infalter = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public PhotoItemData getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = infalter.inflate(R.layout.item_photo, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgItemPhoto);

        holder.imgSelect = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgItemSelect);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.imgPhoto.setTag(position);

    try {

        ImageUtil.showImage(holder.imgPhoto,"file://" + data.get(position).getSdcardPath() );
        /*if (isActionMultiplePick) {

            holder.imgQueueMultiSelected
                    .setSelected(data.get(position).isSeleted);
        }*/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgPhoto;
    ImageView imgSelect;
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<PhotoItemData> files) {

    try {
        this.data.clear();
        this.data.addAll(files);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: anything in LogCat?

Comment: nothing in LogCat